# Inverting data and attribute using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT I want to tranform this XML:

```
<exchangeRates>
    <rate country="aud">0.97</rate>
</exchangeRates>
```

into this XML:

```
<xchgRates>
    <entry xrate="0.97">aud</entry>
</xchgRates>
```

EDIT: exchangeRates needs to become xchgRates. Changed xRate to xrate to match correct solution.

Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that is shorter, more readable and maintainable than the currently accepted answer. Detailed explanation is provided.

Comment: Edit: the solutions provided haven't addressed exchangeRates becoming xchgRates

Comment: The new element name in your question seemed a typo... I have edited my answer and it now produces the exact wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A complete and short solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="exchangeRates">
  <xchgRates>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xchgRates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="rate">
  <entry xrate="{.}">
   <xsl:value-of select="@country"/>
  </entry>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<exchangeRates>
    <rate country="aud">0.97</rate>
</exchangeRates>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<xchgRates>
   <entry xrate="0.97">aud</entry>
</xchgRates>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Using and overriding the identity rule**/template
2. **Using AVT** (**[Attribute-Value-Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**) is recommended as it needs less typing and results in shorter, more understandable and maintainable code.

Almost all attributes of the XSLT instructions with a few exceptions (notably the `select` attribute) allow AVTs.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but something like this should work:

```
<xsl:template match="exchangeRates/rate">
    <entry>
         <xsl:attribute name="xRate"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="@country" />
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```